# LARAVEL 8 SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146

Tags: php, laravel

всем привет, при запуске выходит ошибка, запрос в коде на таблицу poligon.sessions не могу найти, т.к. самой такой таблицы нет, не могу найти запрос и не могу понять, как он автоматически прописал этот запрос?

миграции и сиды проходят, в MySQL WorkBench все отображается правильно, таблицы poligon.sessions нет

LARAVEL 8 SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'poligon.sessions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `sessions` where `id` = 60Q7qeOmlRSuiDN6xZHnDRKsiT5ZSAqdN4X7Dub7 limit 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#driver-prerequisites)

Миграция

```
Schema::create('sessions', function ($table) {
    $table->string('id')->primary();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->index();
    $table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();
    $table->text('user_agent')->nullable();
    $table->text('payload');
    $table->integer('last_activity')->index();
});
```

или через консоль

```
php artisan session:table

php artisan migrate
```

Comment: спасибо тебе большое друг мой :)

Comment: @zadrog примете ответ, если он решил вашу проблему

Comment: А как это сделать?